# Issue with Apache 2.4.43 https while using proxy pass

Tags: java, apache, jboss, webserver

I am new to Apache configuration with Jboss EAP 7 as web server. I am using Jboss EAP 7 as the web server where i deployed my application which is working good. Its listening to http with port no as 8080. When i try to access the application from Apache with http , its working well. But the same from https is not working. Apache version is 2.4.43 . The below is my configuration.

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
ProxyPass /Hello http://x.x.x.x:8080/Hello
ProxyPassReverse /Hello http://x.x.x.x:8080/Hello
</VirtualHost>

The above works fine.

But the below is not working

<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:443>
ProxyPass /Hello http://x.x.x.x:8080/Hello
ProxyPassReverse /Hello http://x.x.x.x:8080/Hello
</VirtualHost>
```

Getting the following error. Not sure what could be the issue?The following is the error logd from Apache server:

```
[proxy:error] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01084: pass request body failed to x.x.x.x:8080 
[proxy_http:error]   AH01097: pass request body failed to x.x.x.x:8080
```

From the browser, i get 504 error message like below.

The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Thanks,

Suresh

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be issue with my certificates. The same configuration is working fine with valid certificate in other environments.